# Need help setting up my ( java) Odata service to send binaries via the SDK to my SAP system (Update)

Tags: java, sdk, odata, s4sdk

I followed the SDK course and the blog. It was possible for me through the business partner to do a read operation. Now I have my own service and want to use the generated VDM data to easily send data to my SAP system via an update.

```
    @Override    
protected void doGet(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {

        BarcodeFile barcode1 = new BarcodeFile();
        barcode1.setDATA("VGVzdA==");
        barcode1.setDokumentyp("TXT");
        barcode1.setDokId("18032019");

                new DefaultUploadService() 
                .createBarcodeFile(barcode1)            
                .execute();

        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.getWriter().write(new Gson().toJson(barcode1));


    } catch (final ODataException e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        response.getWriter().write(e.getMessage());
    }
```

I am in training and so I have little experience. I also found no blog / document which helps me.
Thank you for your efforts

Comment: What do you mean by "I followed the SDK course and the blog.."?

Comment: @Wufo: I think what he means is the [OpenSAP course](https://open.sap.com/courses/s4h13) and the [blog post series](https://blogs.sap.com/2017/05/10/first-steps-with-sap-s4hana-cloud-sdk/).

Comment: @Markus: In general I would assume that [this post](https://blogs.sap.com/2018/04/30/deep-dive-10-with-sap-s4hana-cloud-sdk-generating-java-vdm-for-s4hana-custom-odata-service/) should help you get started. In general you should have an `updateBarcodeFile` method with which you could update an existing `BarcodeFile` entity. On a side note: you should use the `BarcodeFile` returned by the `execute` method call to write into the response to see the actually created entity.

Comment: Hello many thanks for your quick answers. 
My service works. There was a problem at the SAP backend.
(@)Wufo : yes I meant the [OpenSAP Course](https://open.sap.com/courses/s4h13) and [blog post series](https://blogs.sap.com/2017/05/10/first-steps-with-sap-s4hana-cloud-sdk/)
@ChristophSchubert : I have read the deep-dive-10 post but did not understand how should i build my query.
It was important to know if im on the right way.

And now its working ;)

thx to all

Comment: Glad I could help! Can you then kindly add an answer? That way we know that this question does not need attention any more.

Answer (score 0):

Ah this is the way to close this thread.
Many thanks for the helping me to solve this issue.
My code is working fine.
Greetings Markus